# Convert Factor format to hour and minute format in R

Tags: r

I have a column in a Factor format.

```
12:07:35
09:35:20
14:10:15
15:50:03
09:35:20
14:10:15
12:50:03
```

I'd like to convert a factor column format to hour and minute format. Then group by hour.

```
09:00
12:00
14:00
15:00
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted exactly that output, I'd use a combination of the lubridate package and some base R date handling, like so:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(~timestamp,
              "12:07:35",
              "09:35:20",
              "14:10:15",
              "15:50:03",
              "09:35:20",
              "14:10:15",
              "12:50:03")

df %>% 
    mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
           timestamp = floor_date(timestamp, unit = "1 hour"),
           timestamp = sprintf("%02d:00", hour(timestamp)))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 1
#>   timestamp
#>       <chr>
#> 1     12:00
#> 2     09:00
#> 3     14:00
#> 4     15:00
#> 5     09:00
#> 6     14:00
#> 7     12:00
```

If you want the nearest hour instead, use `round_date()` rather than `floor_date()`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `lubridate`, but, having faced similar problems in other languages, I strongly recommend using a library of some kind for working with date/time information, as they will catch all sorts of edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding of your question

```
library(dplyr)

List=c('12:07:35'
,'09:35:20'
,'14:10:15'
,'15:50:03'
,'09:35:20'
,'14:10:15'
,'12:50:03')
List=as.factor(List)
List=data.frame(List)
List1 = List %>%
  mutate(MIN=substr(List,1,5), HOUR=substr(List,1,2)) %>%
  group_by(HOUR) %>%
  count()

> List1
# A tibble: 4 × 2
   HOUR     n
  <chr> <int>
1    09     2
2    12     2
3    14     2
4    15     1
```